Why there is an undercut on the standoff and how it affects its strength?
This picture shows two M3 standoffs: a brass one and a steel one.

The threaded part of the brass one has a minimum diameter dictated by M3 thread specifications, but the steel one has a pronounced undercut at its base with much smaller diameter (see blue arrow). It weakens the standoff to a point that it can be snapped when tightening with a small screwdriver. Why is it there? Does the brass standoff have a higher torsional strength than the steel one, with and without the undercut?

The threads in the steel part are formed by rolling an undersize rod in a roller die set, which creates thread tips that have a major diameter greater than that of the unrolled rod- whereas the brass part has cut threads in it. Rolling is cheaper because it is faster. the unthreaded shank of the steel part is to furnish clearance between the roller die set and the shoulder of the steel part.

If anyone else was curious as to how this works, here is a short video that explained it for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNZjZnwOx90

what do you think about strength?  It seems to me it's a bit smaller diameter, but without the thread-induced stress risers.  I doubt it weakens the bolt, unless the rolling process does.

@TigerGuy Rolled threads are stronger than cut threads. However, that's probably not of interest in such an application, as the strength is minor consideration.

Interestingly, Brass appears to have a lower shear strength than Steels of various types, so perhaps geometry or internal stress due to rolling does reduce the part's longevity: https://unipunch.com/support/charts/material-specifications/
The page on rolled vs. cut says the tensile strength is stronger for rolled - I assume that means in the direction of the bolt's axis, not necessarily for torque applied during fastening?

An undercut at the base of the standoff is to insure that it can be fitted flush with the tapped hole. This makes the standoff stronger than if, without an undercut, the standoff cannot be tightened flush. The allowable tightening torque should be per the rating for the size of thread even with the undercut. An excessive undercut of course can prematurely fail.
